# I created a Jewish app that I think will be useful to others, can I promote it on Mi Yodeya?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-promotion

I created a Jewish app, and I was wondering if I can post a link to the app on Mi Yodeya, would that be considered Spam?

Comment: well what is it already i'm dying to now don't tease us like that

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Ha. nothing special, just a Zmanim/Hebrew calendar app. Other such (and even better) apps exists, however, I created this for fun and decided to release it on the Google Play store.

Comment: Cool, great I'll check it out- You are special! (Sanhedrin, that Mishnah)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you believe, for example, that the existence of your app is relevant to answering a question on Mi Yodeya, it *may* be OK to write an answer to that effect, but make sure to read this page from our Help Center first: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/promotion.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so in [a "community ad"](/tags/community-ads/info). Unfortunately, Stack Exchange is not currently accepting such ads. Keep an eye out here on Meta, or keep an eye on [this Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364556), to know when it will do so again.

There's also a "Web site URL" (or some such) field in [your profile](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/22460/mendelg), and you can link to your app there.