# Is my answer considered spam?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-promotion, spam

A while ago I asked a question:

[Is there a website that has a list of Roshei Teivot in text format?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/128180/22460)

Since I couldn't find a good resource for my answer, I have decided to create my own solution.

This solution is an app I created.

So, I have posted [an answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/132348/22460) to my question saying:

> Since I haven't found any good resources on Roshei Teivot, I have
> decided to go ahead and create an app for a list of Roshei Teivot. You
> can look for it on the app/play store.

- Is this answer considered spam, as I'm "kind of" sending future readers to the app/play store.
  (Note: I haven't included any links)

---

On the other hand, if you take a look at my other question:

[I created a Jewish app that I think will be useful to others, can I promote it on Mi Yodeya?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5467/22460)

One of the answers says:

> If you believe, for example, that the existence of your app is
> relevant to answering a question on Mi Yodeya, it *may* be OK to write
> an answer to that effect

- So, is my answer considered spam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer which you quote in part reads in full:

> If you believe, for example, that the existence of your app is relevant to answering a question on Mi Yodeya, it *may* be OK to write an answer to that effect, but make sure to read this page from our Help Center first: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/promotion.

Please do read and follow that! But in my opinion posting a link to the app in that answer would be appropriate and in accordance with the rules, at least if you also have other answers on the site unrelated to your app.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the app link. the thing is that the app is a _paid_ app. Do you think that matters?

Comment: @MendelG I don't see anything in the policy saying that that matters, and I don't see why it should. The point here is intellectual honesty, which you accomplish by acknowledging your affiliation and by participating here more broadly than for self-promotion.